# Google Analytics (not with Tag manager), send page view with hashed URL and AJAX, SPA type web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

We have a web application (AJAX/SPA type) that I did not build but need to track analytics on.  The URLs are not very nice or symantic and they are ran via Ajax in most cases.  I don't really have control over what gets generated.
What I want to do is on an onClick, a function is called so I can track the "pageview" of the Ajaxed called page.

The URL format that gets generated in the address bar is something like this:
https://subdomain.mysite.com/subpage/myfoopage.html#details=ecatalogue.54321
https://subdomain.mysite.com/subpage/mybarpage.html#details=ecatalogue.12345

Given that the URL has a hash AND a period in it, I have NO idea how this will show up in Analytics and before I go sending "sends" to my analytics dashboard, I thought I would reach out for some advice.  Thank you in advance.

My current code I was thinking of using would be the ga set and ga send.
But given the hash, I an wondering if I should use window.location.href to send it all or do I have to modify the URL before sning it to Analytics.

So currently, simply using jQuery for simplicity sake:

```
$(".somelink").on('click', function(){
//let the hash load
 setTimeout(function(){
   var myPath = window.location.href;  //https://subdomain.mysite.com/subpage/myfoopage.html#details=ecatalogue.54321
    ga('set', 'page', myPath);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  },2000);
});
```

Would the path in full get sent with the hash and the period or would it add a special "+" character or something or do I need to so some string parsing to get rid of the hash and the period in the location path??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send the hash and anything after it, you may should remove it from the path string using split method or whatever like this.

The best way to test it is configuring a "development" property in GA and send the data to it. After your validation you can change the property id to the production one.

Comment: I have not messed with custom properties, but this sounds like it could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The hash will come through. Using your example of:

```
https://subdomain.mysite.com/subpage/myfoopage.html#details=ecatalogue.54321
```

In GA it will show up like so:

```
/https://subdomain.mysite.com/subpage/myfoopage.html#details=ecatalogue.54321
```

With the additional / in front, since you're only supposed to send the page path.

So I recommend you parse out the hostname and protocol from it.

Comment: So GA will grab the hostname then I just send the path and hash.  Got ya.  Thank you.